# Include CocoasMQTT library in swift framework project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am pretty new to swift and iOS development. I am trying to write a framework using swift 2.0. I need to import the [CocoasMQTT](https://github.com/emqtt/CocoaMQTT) library in my framework. I am using cocoa pods approach for this and i added

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'CocoaMQTT'
```

in my pod file. After this I pod install. Now in my Pods directory I can only see debug.xconfig and release.xconfig files(in xcode directory view). I think this should have worked but I am unable to import the library in my swift classes as it says that "No Such module 'CocoaMQTT'" when i try

```
import CocoaMQTT
```

in my code.

Can anyone explain if I am doing something wrong. P.S., as I have included use_frameworks! and I am using iOS version 9 for development so I think I don't have to write the Objective C bridge header.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem to. My problem cause about using CocoaPods. I think you open .xcodeproj file by Xcode but if you install pods you must open .xcworkspacefile. You should look raywenderlich's forum for using cocoapods.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

Answer (score 0):

Close your xcode after `pod install`, and open the .xcworkspace file generated by Cocoapods.